# Getting rid of <p> wrap in CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, concrete5, redactor

I am using Concrete5 5.7.5.2 as my CMS and decided to try using CKEditor instead of the shipped Redactor. The problem I am having is that anytime I try to insert a content block it wraps a paragraph tag around my content.

I have tried the following settings in my config.js, but they don't seem to change the problem.

```
config.autoParagraph = false;
config.enterMode = 2;
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR // pressing the ENTER Key puts the <br/> tag
config.shiftEnterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P; //pressing the SHIFT + ENTER Keys puts the <p> tag
```

Part of the reason I am using CKEditor instead of Redactor is because this is the exact issue I had with Redactor. I tried all of the recommended fixes in Redactor as well, and it didn't fix it there either. Could it be something beyond these two plugins? Core?

You help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

open CKEditor.php (/src/Editor)

look for this code block

```
$options = array_merge(
$options,
array(
    'plugins' => implode(',', $plugins),
    'stylesSet' => 'concrete5styles',
    'filebrowserBrowseUrl' => 'a',
    'uploadUrl' => (string)URL::to('/ccm/system/file/upload'),
    'language' => $this->getLanguageOption(),
    'customConfig' => '',
    'allowedContent' => true,
    'image2_captionedClass' => 'content-editor-image-captioned',
    'image2_alignClasses' => array(
        'content-editor-image-left',
        'content-editor-image-center',
        'content-editor-image-right'
    )
)
);
```

add these two key value pairs

```
'enterMode' => 2,
'shiftEnterMode' => 2
```

the code should look like this afterward

```
$options = array_merge(
$options,
array(
    'plugins' => implode(',', $plugins),
    'stylesSet' => 'concrete5styles',
    'filebrowserBrowseUrl' => 'a',
    'uploadUrl' => (string)URL::to('/ccm/system/file/upload'),
    'language' => $this->getLanguageOption(),
    'customConfig' => '',
    'allowedContent' => true,
    'image2_captionedClass' => 'content-editor-image-captioned',
    'image2_alignClasses' => array(
        'content-editor-image-left',
        'content-editor-image-center',
        'content-editor-image-right'
    ),
    'enterMode' => 2,
    'shiftEnterMode' => 2
)
);
```